# Custom physical keyboard mappings without root

Tags: external-keyboard

I have a physical bluetooth keyboard.

I want, as I do on my computer, to remap the caps lock key to the escape key.

I see in settings there are shortcut keys but no way to remap keys.

[image]

Is this possible with an Android phone? I'm using Android 13

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to remap keyboard shortcut?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249423/44325)

Comment: Thanks. The files mentioned in the linked Android  document seem to require root access, however. So I've edited my post to specify that I want to do it without root.

Comment: There was a link to ExKeyMo https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/ . It should help you. Disclaimer: I'm the developer.